# jQuery DOM Traversing

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

I got the following source code, which is generated by a PHP server file:

```
<div class="row">
<img src="xxx.jpg" data-imgurl="xxx.jpg" width="200"/>
<img src="xxx.jpg" data-imgurl="xxx.jpg" width="200"/>
<img src="xxx.jpg" data-imgurl="xxx.jpg" width="200"/>

<div class="test"></div>

<img src="xxx.jpg" data-imgurl="xxx.jpg" width="200"/>
<img src="xxx.jpg" data-imgurl="xxx.jpg" width="200"/>
<img src="xxx.jpg" data-imgurl="xxx.jpg" width="200"/>

<div class ="test"></div>

<img src="xxx.jpg" data-imgurl="xxx.jpg" width="200"/>
<img src="xxx.jpg" data-imgurl="xxx.jpg" width="200"/>
<img src="xxx.jpg" data-imgurl="xxx.jpg" width="200"/>

<div class ="test"></div>

</div>
```

Now I want to track a click on any image and display the full sized image in the appropriate #test div. However I don't know, how to access the closest #test div, because this is the place where the image should append.

```
$('.row').on('click', 'img', function(

)};
```

EDIT: the clicked image should only appear in the first following .test class.. and not in all following.

Greetings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, there should not be any duplicate id's on the page. You need to use a class instead.
Then you can use like,

```
$('.row').on('click', 'img', function(){
     $(this).nextUntil(".test").next().empty().append($(this).clone());
});
```

or

```
$('.row').on('click', 'img', function(){
     $(this).nextUntil(".test").next().html($(this).clone());
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/83/)

Comment: Thanks but I think I need to be more specific … I've fixed your mentioned id problem but when it comes to my main problem I forgot to mention, that the clicked image should only appear in the first next <div class="test">, and not in every following.

Comment: Thanks !! Works just as it was supposed to

Answer (score 1):

Use `.next`. From the jQuery documentation:

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.

Your code should look like:

```
$('.row').on('click', 'img', function({
    $(this).next('div')    //Append the image here
});
```

Also, as Anoop said, using duplicate IDs is invalid HTML and should be replaced by a class.